# Different behavior of awaitAll() in Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When we execute following functions after warmup, we get two different results.

- `good()`: **7ms**
- `bad()`: **618ms**

**Why repeating outside the `coroutineScope{...}` get a result that looks like invoking in serial?**

```kotlin
suspend fun good() =
    buildList {
        coroutineScope {
            // repeat inside the coroutineScope
            repeat(100) {
                add(async { delay(5) })
            }
        }
    }.awaitAll()

suspend fun bad() =
    buildList {
        // repeat out of the coroutineScope
        repeat(100) {
            coroutineScope {
                add(async { delay(5) })
            }
        }
    }.awaitAll()

suspend fun main() {
    // do some warm up
    measureTimeMillis { good() }
        .also { println("good: ${it}ms") }
    measureTimeMillis { bad() }
        .also { println("bad: ${it}ms") }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) of the `coroutineScope` function states:

> This function returns as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed.

Calling `coroutineScope` suspends until all of its children coroutines are complete, so your `bad()` example is running the jobs serially by design.

Comment: Thanks for answering.According to the document, `coroutineScope` wait all children jobs to be complete. Is that impossible to write a suspend function returning a `Deferred` like `suspend fun loadSomethingAsync(): Deferred<*>`? Because `async` builder always require a `CoroutineScope` which is offered by `coroutineScope` or `GlobalScope`(and use `GlobalScope` is not recommended).

Comment: You can create your own CoroutineScope using the `CoroutineScope()` constructor and use that to launch coroutines that are not the children of the coroutine you are launching from. Typically, you would set this up in a property in the class that wants to be able to launch its own independent coroutines, and manage its lifecycle appropriately, like canceling the scope when this class is being torn down. And you don’t need a `suspend` function to be able to return a Deferred.